# Instantiating a watir browser on test failure in Cucumber without using the singleton pattern

Tags: ruby, singleton, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I've been trying to create a ["cucumber seed" project](https://github.com/smoll/cucumber-seed) that I can use to quickly bootstrap a browser-based Acceptance Test suite. [Alister Scott has written](http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/01/five-page-object-anti-patterns/) about a common antipattern of constantly closing and reopening browser windows (which adds unnecessary delay to a test suite), which can be avoided by adding the following to the env.rb file:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new

Before do
  @browser = browser
end

at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```

But I'm unsure of how to incorporate this behavior, while still restarting the browser when a test fails (this ensures that a failed test does not leak browser state and cause a cascade of failures to unrelated scenarios).

My current approach is to wrap `Watir::Browser` instantiation in a `Browser` singleton class, like so:

```
# support/browser.rb

class Browser
  class << self
    def instance
      @browser
    end

    def start(name: 'chrome')
      @name = name
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new(name.to_sym)
    end

    def stop
      @browser.close # if a page hangs this will fail with a selenium unknown error
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error
      puts 'Failed to close old browser (possibly because page is hanging), starting new one!'
    end

    def restart
      stop
      start(name: @name)
    end
  end # singleton methods
end
```

and then call it in my env.rb/hooks file like so:

```
Browser.start

Before do
  @browser = Browser.instance
end

After do |scenario|
  Browser.restart if scenario.failed?
end

at_exit do
  Browser.stop
end
```

Which works, but is there a better way to write this? Something that avoids having to use a singleton, perhaps?

Comment: What is the motivation for avoiding the singleton? I personally like this approach. What problems do you have with it? Another approach could be defining `browser` outside of the scope of your `Before` and `at_exit`. It sounds like you need to have some global state or state that is passed between tests

Comment: I try to avoid the singleton out of habit because it lends itself to poor design, especially if support code gets increasingly complex, and it's not easily unit-testable. But it makes sense, intuitively, that I can't operate on instances of classes if I need to preserve some global state between tests.

Comment: obviously there can be a lot of difference between web apps, but is your fear and code justified or YAGNI?  Have you actually encountered carry-over errors due to browser state with your app?    In the last several years of testing using Watir & Cucumber I've never had this problem myself.  (although I will admit that precisely zero of my tests assume the browser is already on the needed page etc.)  The closest I come is that I check to see if the user I want is already logged in before having the current user logout and then sign-in with the required user.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden the reason I originally coded it was due to a problem with a legacy app I'm currently testing, in which pages hang sporadically due to a hard-to-track-down session bug (restarting the browser lets the tests continue without issue) causing subsequent, unrelated tests to fail. The only other time I can see this being useful is when we're dealing with javascript modals that, if a test fails, leaving it open, it can cause subsequent tests to fail since the modal blocks the "logout" link or any other navigational links from being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this approach would be useful if the application is not stable. I would suggest creating a new instance of browser and closing it at the end of scenario.